# Given y=ax+b, x= cy+d, what will be the range of a * c?

Tags: linear-algebra

TBH, I was asked this question during an interview.

I was completely lost: shouldn't c = 1/a? In what scenario, c will not be equal to 1/a ?

can anyone share some thoughts?

Comment: If $a$ or $c$ is zero.

Comment: This is an imprecise question because it does not have quantifiers for $a,b,c,d,x,y$. I could understand it as "$a,b,c,d$ are such that, for every $x,y$ the conditions $y=ax+b, x=cy+d$ are equivalent" or "$a,b,c,d$ are such that there *exist* $x,y$ such that $y=ax+b, x=cy+d$. The answers for those two cases will be very different. In the first case, $a,c\ne 0$ and $ac=1$. In the second case, $a,c$ (and even $b$) may be arbitrary as you can always take $x$ arbitrary, $y=ax+b$ and $d=x-cy$. I *think* they *probably* meant the first interpretation, but I would like to be 100% sure.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I have to disagree. Since this is an interview question, I believe this question is purposely imprecise, so the interviewers can check whether candidates can "think out of the box". In this case, $1$ is the "correct" answer, but $0$ would be the answer the interviewers want. Bonus points if you add your analysis.

Comment: @player3236 I understand what you mean. On my part, I still struggle to interpret the question in such way so that $0$ and $1$ are in the range but no others. (As you can see, I think it can be interpreted so that the whole $\mathbb R$ is the range.) Maybe the right answer here is to just return the question: "make it precise, then I can solve it". I guess that doesn't get you the job, but at least you keep your dignity of not pretending to be a mind-reader of the examiners.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I made a mistake assuming that $a,b,c,d$ are constants and $x,y$ are variables. Indeed you can ask the examiners to clarify the problem, but the response you will get is probably "interpret it in whatever way you see fit."